# C char pointer get a specific character

Tags: c, string, c-strings

probably a dumb question but how do you access a specific character in a char pointer?

I've tried following...

```
char *pointer = "Hello";
printf("%s", pointer); // prints "Hello"
printf("%s", &pointer[0]); // also prints "Hello"
```

But what I want is printf(???) => "H". A single character. Or the "e". How is that possible?

Comment: Did you look at the `%c` option? ... the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) are long, but still worth reading.

Comment: pointer is the same as &pointer[0], to index into the string use pointer[n] where n is the base 0 index of the character you want.

Comment: Yes, it gives me a random character, so I cannot use %c.

Comment: `&pointer[0]` is equivalent to `pointer` is equivalent to `&*pointer`. And that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pointer` is a pointer to `char`, also called a `char *`.

After `char *pointer = "Hello";`, `pointer` points to the “H”.

When `printf` is given `%s`, it takes a `char *` and prints **all** the characters it finds starting at that location, until a null character is seen.

To tell `printf` to print a single character, pass it the actual character value (not a pointer) and use `%c`:

```
printf("%c", *pointer);
```

or:

```
printf("%c", pointer[0]);
```

or, for the “e” instead of the “H”:

```
printf("%c", pointer[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    char* pointer = "Hello";
```

Creates a pointer and assigns it to the base address of "Hello".

pointer and &pointer[0] are the same thing.

pointer[n] takes the address of "Hello" and offsets it by the number 'n', be sure not to index of the end of the address or you will read rubbish.

So:

```
    pointer[0] = 'H'
    pointer[1] = 'e'
    pointer[2] = 'l'
    pointer[3] = 'l'
    pointer[4] = 'o'
    pointer[5] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of %s property to print out the whole string. You showed me that I can access characters like I'm used to.

Comment: You can also do &pointer[1] to print out just "ello" or anything else, as it will translate into get the address of the position specified at "n".

Answer (score 1):

You want to access the `char` of `char*` simply use `[]` operator, just like arrays.

```
char *pointer = "Hello";
printf("%s", pointer); // ok
printf("%s", &pointer[0]); // wrong way of accessing specific element (it is same as the base address.., thus %s prints the whole thing)
```

Instead you're accessing the address of the first element of `char*` or string literal.. why!

```
printf("%c", pointer[0]); // use this one
```

Just like arrays, access the required element.

However, to get it better, notice here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char *pointer = "Hello";
    printf("%s\n\n", pointer); // ok
    printf("%c", pointer[0]); 

    printf("%p == %p\n", (void *)&pointer[0],(void *)pointer);
    // cast to void * to avoid undefined behavior 
    // pointed out by @ex nihilo 


    printf("%p", pointer+1); 


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
H0x55da21577004 == 0x55da21577004
0x55da21577005
```

as you can see, the `pointer` holds the address of the first element which is: `&pointer[0]` thus you get the same output.

Comment: your comment // wrong! is wrong, both are valid and both will do the same.

Comment: yeah..  as the first element's address & the base address is same... I mean to get the correct element

Comment: You need to cast to `void *` when printing addresses to avoid undefined behavior: e.g. `printf("%p == %p\n", &pointer[0],pointer)` --> `printf("%p == %p\n", (void *)&pointer[0], (void *)pointer)` and `printf("%p", (void *)(pointer+1))`